# How to concatenate two lines using label in sed

Tags: sed, label, concatenation

I have a question if there is some way to detect the end of the line using sed. Bcs I need to concatenate two-line only if the end of the line end with a minus sign - otherwise not.

```
sed -e :a -e '/,$/N; s/-\n*/new_line/; ta' test.txt (that is only what i have and i need to substite new_line for actualy new line)
```

if file is look something like that

```
Here is a random sente-
nc and if random sentec ended with minus it is better to concatenate.
```

RESULT

```
Here is a random sentece and if random sentec ended with minus it is better to concatenate.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you will do that `sed` in any version:

```sh
cat file

foo bar_-
Here is a random sente-
nce and if random sentec ended with minus it is better to concatenate.

# and use sed as
sed -e :a -e '/-$/{N;s/-\n//g;ta' -e '}' file

foo bar_Here is a random sentence and if random sentec ended with minus it is better to concatenate.
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/-$/{N;s/-\n//}' file
```

If the line ends in `-`, append the next line and remove the last character of the first line and the following newline.